# Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0)

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I wrote this small program in `OpenCV` in order to resize an image, and then write that new image:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Mat img_src;
    Mat img_dst;
    Size size(250,250);
    img_src = imread("continuous object.png");
    resize(img_src, img_dst, size);
    imwrite("new_img.png", img_dst);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run the program, I got this error in the resize line:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in resize, file /Users/abc/Documents/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3208
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/abc/Documents/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3208: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize

(lldb)
```

Why is that? What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the image is being read? OpenCV does not throw any errors if the image is not read, instead it will continue processing an empty matrix. Try displaying the img_src through imshow, or using an absolute path to the file.

Comment: You're probably not loading the image correctly, i.e. the path you wrote is invalid.

Comment: i feel as though the space in the file name is causing the issue. but display the image or at least check the result of the read.